# C++ cin to c string dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, cin, cstring

Trying to figure out the reasoning behind the mechanics of c strings.

```
char** text;
text = new char*[5];
for(int i = 0; int < 5; int++) {
  cout << endl << "Enter a phrase: ";
  cin  >> text[i];
  cout << text[i];
}
```

I'm not entirely sure as to why this works for the first 2 iterations, even successfully displaying them, but gets a segfault error on the 3rd iteration.

Comment: Because you've allocated an array of pointers but those pointers point to nothing in particular. `cin` will not perform the additional allocations for you.

Comment: It "works" because you're overwriting random memory that happens to belong to your program on the first two iterations, but not the third.

Answer (score 4):

You are using uninitialized memory. You are experiencing undefined behavior.

The line

```
text = new char*[5];
```

allocated memory for five pointers but those pointers haven't been initialized to point to anything valid. Before you can use `text[i]` to read data, you have to allocate memory for it.

```
for(int i = 0; int < 5; int++) {
  cout << endl << "Enter a phrase: ";
  text[i] = new char[SOME_SIZE_LARGE_ENOUGH_FOR_YOUR_NEED];
  cin  >> text[i];
  cout << text[i];
}
```

Then, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You've allocated memory for 5 pointers, but you are not allocating anything that those five pointers point to. Assuming that you're using a modern 64-bit CPU with 8 byte-wide pointers, your `new` operator allocated exactly 40 bytes, five eight-byte pointers. Their initial contents are random, uninitialized memory, and when you write to them, they get interpreted as pointers to random memory addresses, which end up being corrupted with what you've read from `std::cin`. You got lucky initially, and the first two iterations scribbled over some memory somewhere, but your program continued to limp along, but you won the lottery on the third try; hitting a random address that does not exist, and segfaulting.

Although you can rewrite this to do proper allocation, if you're really trying to write C++, rather than C, here, there's no reason to allocate anything. Why do you want to deal with allocating memory, when C++ will happily do it for you?

```
std::vector<std::string> text;

for(int i = 0; int < 5; int++) 
{
  std::cout << std::endl << "Enter a phrase: ";

  std::string s;

  if (std::getline(std::cin, s).eof())
     break;

  text.push_back(s);

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```